# Windows [10] File Folder Denied Access

Tags: windows, file, windows-10, delete-file

I have a file folder called, `my_folder` it has been created by a program and has been made into a read-only access. I have admin rights to the computer I'm using but when I try to make it non-read-only it says that I don't have access to it. I've tried using Admin Command Prompt and deleting it with Admin rights in the File Explorer. The end goal is to delete the folder.

Here is the error I get when I try to delete it via the File Explorer:
[image: File Deletion Error]

And here is the error I get when trying to do the deletion via Admin Terminal:

```
$> rmdir my_folder
Access is denied
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Permissions issues are my favorite Windows problems! Deleting with admin rights usually works for me. You might try [taking ownership](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-take-ownership-and-get-full-access-to-files-and-folders-in-windows-10/) of the folder and trying again. If that fails try [booting into safe mode](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix it by booting into safe mode.